# Heroku Scheduler custom schedule node.js

Tags: node.js, heroku, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have a node.js script that I would like to run hourly from Monday to Friday, between 9am and 6pm.

How do I get this custom scheduling on Heroku?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it would be to have your Heroku scheduler run your script every hour. In your script, check if the current date/time is within the range you want. If so - continue, otherwise exit.

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now, but I was wondering if there's a better way to do it so the script isn't invoked every time.

Comment: I guess you could do the date calculations directly inside the Procfile, only invoking your node.js script if the date is within your required range.

Comment: After 3 years is this still the only way to do custom scheduling?